# Overriding existing Mui classes using makeStyles

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

So, this can be a very minute implementation issue on my end I think. I used to keep stylesheets completely separate from my component.js file but lately, I started to see some benefits of writing styles inside the component with styled components, emotions, make styles, etc. I tried it on a dummy project and started to implement it out on some components on an app I am working on right now. The reasons were primarily more manageable, dev-experience, and it worked for me.

But then I found myself in this issue of overriding existing mui styles.

For example, I am using material-ui to make this accordion component. And there is a nested property

```
.MuiAccordionSummary-root.Mui-expanded {
    min-height: 64px;
}
```

To edit this is my sass file would be very easy but how do I make it work with make styles?

My current styles look like this

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    borderBottom: '0.5px solid',
    borderBottomColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
    marginBottom: '16px',
    maxHeight: '35px',
  },
  summary: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.complimentory.main,
    borderBottom: '0.5px solid',
    borderBottomColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
    maxHeight: '35px',
    height: '35px',
  },
  title: {
    fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    fontWeight: 'normal',
    fontSize: '14px',
    lineHeight: '14px',
    letterSpacing: '0.266667px',
    textTransform: 'uppercase',
  },
  content: {
    marginTop: '15px',
    fontSize: '14px',
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    lineHeight: '16.8px',
    letterSpacing: '0.375px',
    fontWeight: '400',
    fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
    textAlign: 'left',
  },
}))
```

I am struggling to target it inside makestyles, I think it must be possible, I just am having a hard time as I am not used to it.

Comment: It seems that you're looking for nested selectors, check it out here https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#nesting-selectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll use the [`AccordionSummary`](https://material-ui.com/api/accordion-summary/) as an example on how to override existing styles. The Accordion Summary has 6 CSS rules that can be overridden: root, expanded, focused, disabled, content and expandIcon. You can see this at the [CSS section of the AccordionSummary API page](https://material-ui.com/api/accordion-summary/#css) in Material UI's official documents. Each of these correspond to a Material UI class for the respective component e.g. root for the `AccordionSummary` corresponds to the class `.MuiAccordionSummary-root`. To override these styles, you do it via [overriding styles with classes](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#overriding-styles-with-classes).

Using your example:

1. Create the class name and add the styling in `makeStyles`. I'll create one called `summaryExpanded` and will include the styling `minHeight: '64px'`.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    borderBottom: '0.5px solid',
    borderBottomColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
    marginBottom: '16px',
    maxHeight: '35px',
  },
  summary: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.complimentory.main,
    borderBottom: '0.5px solid',
    borderBottomColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
    maxHeight: '35px',
    height: '35px',
  },
  summaryExpanded: {
    minHeight: '64px',
  },
  title: {
    fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    fontWeight: 'normal',
    fontSize: '14px',
    lineHeight: '14px',
    letterSpacing: '0.266667px',
    textTransform: 'uppercase',
  },
  content: {
    marginTop: '15px',
    fontSize: '14px',
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    lineHeight: '16.8px',
    letterSpacing: '0.375px',
    fontWeight: '400',
    fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
    textAlign: 'left',
  },
}))
```

2. Override the style in the `AccordionSummary` component by accessing the relevant rule name and assigning your custom class. In this case, it is `expanded`, as we are looking to override `.Mui-expanded` in the `AccordionSummary` component.

```
const classes = useStyles();

<Accordion>
  <AccordionSummary
    classes: {{
      expanded: classes.summaryExpanded,
    }}
  >
  </AccordionSummary>
  <AccordionDetail>
  </AccordionDetail>
</Accordion>
```

Comment: This seems to be the solution for me. I am still working on getting a nested element to modify and I have to use "!important" to make sure styles are overridden. Thanks for such an elaborate examplle.

Comment: You're welcome @PradhumnaPancholi! I completely understand; sometimes there's multiple MUI classes that apply to a certain nested element and it gets really tricky trying to override it

Answer (score 4):

You should use `<StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>` at the root of you project

```
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { StyledEngineProvider } from "@mui/material";
import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(
  <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
    <App />{" "}
  </StyledEngineProvider>,
  rootElement
);
```

```
import * as React from "react";
import AppBar from "@mui/material/AppBar";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Toolbar from "@mui/material/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
import MenuIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Menu";
import makeStyles from "@mui/styles/makeStyles";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => {
  return {
    root: {
      backgroundColor: "red",
      color: "pink"
    }
  };
});

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
      <AppBar position="static" className={classes.root}>
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            size="large"
            edge="start"
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="menu"
            sx={{ mr: 2 }}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" component="div" sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
            News
          </Typography>
          <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Working demo here https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-stonebraker-qnh3t

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this - play around override properties.

```
import { Overrides } from "@material-ui/core/styles/overrides";

const overrides: Overrides = {
  MuiExpansionPanelSummary: {
    root: {
      minHeight: "3.25rem",
      "&$expanded": {
        minHeight: "3.25rem",
      },
    },
    content: {
      margin: "0.25rem",
      "&$expanded": {
        margin: "0.25rem",
      },
    },
    expandIcon: {
      padding: "0.5rem",
    },
    expanded: {},
  },
};
```